# Sanitize inline links in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, inline, hyperlink, sanitize

Hy.
So would anybody know how to write a function that would sanitize all links in a specific class that are entered through WYSISWYG editor?
I know about the wordpress in-built sanitize_title function, but I don't know how I could refer to those links(links in a specific class).
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a filter function to filter `the_content()`?

In your functions.php file, include the filter hook:

```
add_filter ( 'the_content', 'your_sanitizer_function');
```

Then also in functions.php write the sanitizing function that will filter the normal output of `the_content()`:

```
function your_sanitizer_function($content){

    /* use some php here to change your content as you see fit...
        for example, $content = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $content);
     */

    return $content;

}
```